# Notation in Actuarial text

Tags: notation, actuarial-science

I am not very knowledgeable in Actuarial Sciences, but I was looking at a text, and found a notation, which I cannot find any references to.

What does:

$_{2|2}q_{1} = 0.288$

mean? I don't think it is simply a variable, but I can't find any info on the net.
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we have
$$_{m|n}q_{x}$$
means the probability that a life aged $x$ dies between time $x + m$ and $x + m + n$.  This has two pieces, one that the life survives to age $x+m$, and then given that, that the life dies by $x+m+n$.  If nothing is written in the place of the $n$ but the bar is still there, then $n$ is assumed to be 1.

Specifically in this case, your symbol means the probability that a life aged 1 dies between time 3 and 5, and in this case that probability is 0.288.